Нужна ли запятая после "скорее"?
"Если генетические изменения происходят во время раннего этапа развития, то, вероятнее всего, будет задействовано большее количество клеток. Если изменение происходит позже, скорее оно затронет определенную область нашего тела или определенный орган".

Нет обособления:
Если генетические изменения происходят во время раннего этапа развития, то, вероятнее всего, будет задействовано большее количество клеток. Если изменение происходит позже, скорее оно затронет определенную область нашего тела или определенный орган.
Пояснение
По правилам слово скорее может быть вводным словом или наречием.

Обособляются вводные сочетания скорее говоря, скорее всего:  Скорее всего, задержусь.

На практике в большинстве случаев скорее не обособляется, в отличие от сочетания скорее говоря, например: В спортивной курточке канареечного или скорее попугайного цвета, красные полосы на груди. В. Астафьев, Печальный детектив.


Но нужно учитывать частные случаи.

Скорее в качестве  вводного слова дифференцирует отношения между однородными членами:  Не верю своим глазам, скорее, не могу поверить.

Авторское выделение слова в художественном (стихотворном!) тексте: Я склонен думать, гражданин судья, // Что прокурор сегодня был поддавши, // Ведь нападавшим вовсе не был я, // А я, скорее, даже – пострадавший. В. Высоцкий, Я склонен думать, гражданин судья...

Нет обособления при сравнении: Скорее похож на отца, чем на мать. Скорее скандинав, нежели славянин. Скорее умрёт, чем отдаст свою квартиру.

Нет обособления при противопоставлении: Статьи здесь расположены не по алфавиту, а скорее по внутренней логике самого предмета.


РЕШЕНИЕ
Приведенный текст относится к медицинской тематике, и там нужно подчеркнуть сравнение: вероятнее всего — скорее. Если поставить запятую, то непонятно, куда относится слово скорее. С другой стороны, это слово  уж выделено своей позицией в начале предложения (то скорее).
